# Geany "LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed"

Tags: geany

I'm doing this Ruby on Rails tutorial, and everytime I input

```
:~/rails_projects/first_app$ geany .gitignore
```

I get this

```
(geany:12043): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertioN                      
`GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
@ubuntu:~/rails_projects/first_app$ geany .gitignore

(geany:12369): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion     
`GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
```

The text editor still opens, but the terminal doesn't let me input anything unless I close the text editor, unlike the tutorial where he has it open, and the terminal still works.How can I get the functioning terminal with the text editor?

Comment: It would to send a backtrace to the [Geany mailing list](http://www.geany.org/Support/MailingList). At the page [Stop on warnings](http://geany.org/manual/hacking.html#stop-on-warnings) you'll find a description how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same question.
Any ideas on how to correct it??

The way I found to continue to use the command line and still have the geany opened is:

```
 $ geany file &
 $ <ctrl+c>
```

It's useful, but not perfect. 
A solution would be good

Comment: I changed to gedit, it has a ton of plugins that makes it look and function like Textmate, highly recommended.

Answer (score -1):

Cut and paste the following bash function definition into your bash profile ~/.bash_profile to use this from a login bash terminal (or into ~/.bashrc to use this from a non-login terminal). This function will be available only in terminals started after this change is made.

```
geany() { 
    $(which geany) --no-msgwin --no-session "$@" &>/dev/null & disown
}
```

Now typing **geany** followed by zero or more filenames will have the desired effect.

Explanation:

**$(which geany)** finds the path to geany by searching your PATH, and substitutes that path in place of the text **$(which geany)**.

The options **--no-msgwin** and **--no-session** are optional, but respectively start geany without its message window at the bottom and without remembering to open files that were open the last time geany was closed.

**"$@"** is the bash way to substitute into this command the rest of your command line (i.e. all the filenames you type after you type **geany** to use this function).

**&>/dev/null** redirects geany's standard output and standard error output to /dev/null which stops any messages from geany being displayed in the console.

**& disown** runs geany as a separate process that is not a child process of the terminal that starts geany. So it is immediately not a job associated with the terminal, and no termination message will appear in the terminal when you quit geany.